# Divide number into n equal parts

Tags: python, numpy, data-manipulation

I need to divide a number into n equal parts in Python. The output should be a list with tuples containing each part's minimum and maximum value.

For example, if the input is 25, the output should be [(1, 5), (6, 10), (11, 15), (16, 20), (21, 25)].

Comment: How do you divide 13 ?

Comment: you need to share more details.
If the input is 6, output?
[(1,3), (4,6)] or [(1,2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What is that "anything"?

Comment: Okay, cool! Do you have a question? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first half is what you're thinking of, but like others have commented, it depends on number being divisible by n. I've taken the liberty of partitioning numbers not divisible by n with `float` edges.

```
def partition(number, n):
    if number % n == 0: # check if number divisible by n
        width = number // n
        return [(1 + i*width, width + i*width) for i in range(n)]
    else:
        x = np.linspace(1, number, n+1)
        return [(x[i], x[i+1]) for i in range(n)]
```